# the University of California, San Diego

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Is it correct to use or remove the definite article in the following sentence?

> Beachgoers discovered a 4-foot lancetfish washed up near the Scripps Institution of Oceanography at **the** University of California, San Diego Tuesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘The’ should be used, firstly because ‘The’ is used to talk about specific things in this context it is referring to a university.

Also from my understanding I believe ‘The University of California’ is the full name of the university as opposed to simply ‘University of California’.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English or Urdu?

Comment: I am a native English speaker from England.

Comment: The sentence as it is written by CNN is used  without "the."

Comment: It would be more proper to use ‘the’